# How to set image for div while collapse then if I click expand in need to show content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a three div with expand collapse functionality. if I expand one div I need to set some image to other div. if i back to normal mode i need to original content what exist inside that div

```js
$("a.expansion-btn").click(function (){
  classes = this.className;
  var divNumber = classes.slice(-1);
   var toGetId = "#div-"+divNumber;
  if ($(toGetId).hasClass("expanded-div")){
   $(".normal-div").removeClass("compressed-div");
   $(".normal-div").removeClass("expanded-div");
  }
  else{
   $(".normal-div").removeClass("compressed-div");
   $(".normal-div").removeClass("expanded-div");
   $(".normal-div").addClass("compressed-div");
   $(toGetId).removeClass("compressed-div");
   $(toGetId).addClass("expanded-div");    
  }  
});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.contenth1{
  height:20%;
}
.contenth2{
  height:70%;
}
.container{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
}
.normal-div{
  width:33.33%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  border:2px solid black;
  float:left;
}
.expanded-div{
    width:80%;
}
.compressed-div{
  width:10%;
}
#div-1{
   
}
#div-2{
   
}
#div-3{
  
}
a.expansion-btn{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  right:10px;
  font-weight:bold;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="normal-div" id="div-1">
    <div class="contenth1">
      <a class="expansion-btn exp-1">click</a>
    </div >
    <div class="contenth2">one</div>
    </div>
  <div class="normal-div" id="div-2">
  <div class="contenth1">
      <a class="expansion-btn exp-2">click</a>
    </div>
    <div class="contenth2">two</div>
    </div>
  <div class="normal-div" id="div-3">
    <div class="contenth1">
      <a class="expansion-btn exp-3">click</a>
    </div>
    <div class="contenth2">three</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Example:-
In normal Mode Works Fine
[image]

Example 1:-
While Expand div other two div I need to hide the content and show some glyphicons some thing like this image
[image]

Comment: images are not opening

Comment: I don't know how to set image while expand div

Comment: I mean the images you included in question are not opening. edit the question

Comment: To show an image in the divs either set their backgroungImage css value or include a hidden img element and show it as needed.

Comment: While do expand in other two div I need to hide original content like one,two,three and I need to show some glyphicons. If back to normal mode currently what am showing same

Comment: Set image css also fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add some background image to `.compressed-div` class. And `display:none` to `.compressed-div .contenth2`

Also, I have improved selectors for selecting current parent so that you dont have to rely on id and counter

```js
$("a.expansion-btn").click(function (){
  var thisDiv = $(this).closest('.normal-div');
  if (thisDiv.hasClass("expanded-div")){
   $(".normal-div").removeClass("compressed-div");
   $(".normal-div").removeClass("expanded-div");
  }
  else{
   $(".normal-div").removeClass("compressed-div");
   $(".normal-div").removeClass("expanded-div");
   $(".normal-div").addClass("compressed-div");
   $(thisDiv).removeClass("compressed-div");
   $(thisDiv).addClass("expanded-div");    
  }  
});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.contenth1{
  height:20%;
}
.contenth2{
  height:70%;
}
.container{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
}
.normal-div{
  width:33.33%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  border:2px solid black;
  float:left;
}
.expanded-div{
    width:80%;
}
.compressed-div{
  width:10%;
  background:url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTCN90DSaAG4pFAZaMxlsrfTUAebqMI4ZOTwjCCDvoVL7caW9mj");
}
.compressed-div .contenth2{
 display:none;
}
#div-1{
   
}
#div-2{
   
}
#div-3{
  
}
a.expansion-btn{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  right:10px;
  font-weight:bold;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="normal-div" id="div-1">
    <div class="contenth1">
      <a class="expansion-btn exp-1">click</a>
    </div >
    <div class="contenth2">one</div>
    </div>
  <div class="normal-div" id="div-2">
  <div class="contenth1">
      <a class="expansion-btn exp-2">click</a>
    </div>
    <div class="contenth2">two</div>
    </div>
  <div class="normal-div" id="div-3">
    <div class="contenth1">
      <a class="expansion-btn exp-3">click</a>
    </div>
    <div class="contenth2">three</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: content need to hide other than click

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I added `gif` just for fun but you can replace it with normal image.

And if you don't like repeated background, set `background-repeat:no-repeat;` in `.coverUp`

And if you wanna see the content too inside those `compressed div` then remove `z-index` of `.coverUp`

```js
$("a.expansion-btn").click(function (){
  classes = this.className;
  var divNumber = classes.slice(-1);
   var toGetId = "#div-"+divNumber;
  if ($(toGetId).hasClass("expanded-div")){
   $(".normal-div").removeClass("compressed-div expanded-div");
  }
  else{
   $(".normal-div").removeClass("compressed-div expanded-div").addClass("compressed-div");
   $(toGetId).removeClass("compressed-div").addClass("expanded-div");    
  }  
});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.contenth1{
  height:20%;
}
.contenth2{
  height:70%;
}
.container{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
}
.normal-div{
  width:33.33%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  border:2px solid black;
  float:left;
}
.expanded-div{
    width:80%;
}
.compressed-div{
  width:10%;
}
.coverUp{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  background-color:white;
  background-image:url('http://www.downgraf.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/01-progress.gif');
  background-position:center;
  background-size:contain;
  left:0;
  display:none;
  z-index:-1;
}
.compressed-div .coverUp{
  display:block;
}

#div-1{
   
}
#div-2{
   
}
#div-3{
  
}
a.expansion-btn{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  right:10px;
  font-weight:bold;
  cursor:pointer;
  z-index:999;
}
.compressed-div .contenth2{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="normal-div" id="div-1">
    <div class="coverUp"></div>
    <div class="contenth1">
      <a class="expansion-btn exp-1">click</a>
    </div >
    <div class="contenth2">one</div>
  </div>
  <div class="normal-div" id="div-2">
    <div class="coverUp"></div>
  <div class="contenth1">
      <a class="expansion-btn exp-2">click</a>
    </div>
    see it?
    <div class="contenth2">two</div>
    </div>
  <div class="normal-div" id="div-3">
    <div class="coverUp"></div>
    <div class="contenth1">
      <a class="expansion-btn exp-3">click</a>
    </div>
    <div class="contenth2">three</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: while expand  In other two div need to click button

Comment: sorry for that. try it now. let me know if anything is missing

Comment: sure, hide only what exist inside this  <div class="contenth2">one</div>

Comment: ok. so you wanna set the background but it also hides everything so you just wanna hide that. did I get that right?

Comment: ok. done. I added some text in the middle one for you to see.

Comment: @kittyCat try to minimize the code as much as possible